# Difference between Action<object, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs> and RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I'm using a BackgroundWorker.
I tried to register an handler which is an Action, like this:

```
   public void Backup(Action<object, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs> completionEventHandler)
   {
      _backupWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += completionEventHandler;
   }
```

But, I'm receiving the error:

```
   Cannot implicitly convert type 
   'System.Action<object,System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs>' to
   'System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler'
```

As far as I know, a

```
   Action<object,System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs>
```

is just a

```
   delegate void Action(object,System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
```

and RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler is just

```
   delegate void RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
```

So, they both delegates of the same type (same parameters and same return type). So why can't I use the Action where a RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler is expected ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delegate object of a different delegate type is never convertible, even if the delegate signature is exactly the same.  The trivial solution is to use a lambda expression to invoke the delegate when the event is fired.  Like this:

```
public void Backup(Action<object, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs> completionEventHandler) {
    _backupWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ea) => completionEventHandler(s, ea);
}
```